# Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: xml, excel, powershell

I'm trying to import an Excel file to PowerShell and then save it as a XML file. I got an Excel file and a XML template. What I have done is at the below:

```bsh
# define XML configuration template
$config = "C:\Users\mustafaal\Desktop\StajyerMustafaAl\Gorev\XMLTemplate_v2.ps1"
Import-Csv C:\Users\mustafaal\Desktop\StajyerMustafaAl\Gorev\VariablesDeneme.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $xml = "C:\Users\mustafaal\Desktop\StajyerMustafaAl\Gorev\MySampleConfig" + $_.UserName + ".xml"
    Write-Host $_.username
    Write-Host $xml
    [xml]$x = (&$config) -f $_.UserName, $_.SwitchIP, $_.SwitchPort, $_.MACAddress
    $x.Save($xml)
}
```

So basicly I'm trying to save XML files for every username in Excel file.

I'm getting this error:

```
Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format.
At C:\Users\mustafaal\Desktop\StajyerMustafaAl\Gorev\deneme1.ps1:14 char:1
+ [xml]$x = (&$config) -f $_.UserName, $_.SwitchIP, $_.SwitchPort, $_.MACAddress
```

XML template sample:

```xml
<AttributeList>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="Ethernet (15)" value="15" operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-Port-Type" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="Login-User (1), Framed-User (2), Authenticate-Only (8)" value="1,2,8" operator="BELONGS_TO" name="Service-Type" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue={1} value={1} operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-IP-Address" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue={2} value={2} operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-Port-Id" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue={3} value={3} operator="EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE" name="Calling-Station-Id" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="TEIDOM\"{0} value="TEIDOM\"{0} operator="EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE" name="User-Name" type="Radius:IETF"/>
</AttributeList>
```

CSV sample:

```
UserName,SwitchIP,SwitchPort,MACAddress
AHMETO,10.101.254.104,7,288023041d83
ahmett,10.101.254.136,4,480fcf4a6719
```

Basically I need to replace `{}` in the XML file with the variables in the CSV file, but I'm getting a string format error.

**Edit:** Okay now I have found the problem, there are other codes with `{}` and I made them double, but now I got a new error:

> to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'ahmett' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 5, position 84.

Comment: What is the content of `XMLTemplate_v2.ps1`? `(&$config)` executes that script, so it would need to output a single template string for `-f` to operate on.

Comment: i added a piece of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute values in your template must be in quotes. Change this:

```xml
<AttributeList>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="Ethernet (15)" value="15" operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-Port-Type" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="Login-User (1), Framed-User (2), Authenticate-Only (8)" value="1,2,8" operator="BELONGS_TO" name="Service-Type" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue={1} value={1} operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-IP-Address" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue={2} value={2} operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-Port-Id" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue={3} value={3} operator="EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE" name="Calling-Station-Id" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="TEIDOM\"{0} value="TEIDOM\"{0} operator="EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE" name="User-Name" type="Radius:IETF"/>
</AttributeList>
```

into this:

```xml
<AttributeList>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="Ethernet (15)" value="15" operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-Port-Type" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="Login-User (1), Framed-User (2), Authenticate-Only (8)" value="1,2,8" operator="BELONGS_TO" name="Service-Type" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="{1}" value="{1}" operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-IP-Address" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="{2}" value="{2}" operator="EQUALS" name="NAS-Port-Id" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="{3}" value="{3}" operator="EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE" name="Calling-Station-Id" type="Radius:IETF"/>
    <RuleAttribute displayValue="TEIDOM\{0}" value="TEIDOM\{0}" operator="EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE" name="User-Name" type="Radius:IETF"/>
</AttributeList>
```

Also, you need to load the template as regular text, so you can fill in the values using the format operator (`-f`). Once that is done you can either save the data as text:

```bsh
$template = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\template.xml' | Out-String
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $filename = 'C:\path\to\{0}.xml' -f $_.UserName
    $template -f $_.UserName, $_.SwitchIP, $_.SwitchPort, $_.MACAddress |
        Set-Content $filename
}
```

or parse the filled-in template to an XML object and save that:

```bsh
$template = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\template.xml' | Out-String
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $filename = 'C:\path\to\{0}.xml' -f $_.UserName
    [xml]$xml = $template -f $_.UserName, $_.SwitchIP, $_.SwitchPort, $_.MACAddress
    $xml.Save($filename)
}
```

The latter has the advantage that the parser will validate the XML data and throw an error in case something about it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in format like that:

```
$x = [xml](Get-Content $config)
$x | Select-Object -Property UserName, SwitchIP, SwitchPort, MACAddress
$x.Save($xml)
```

If You have config file in proper form it will by something like that ;)

Comment: now im getting this error: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error:
as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

Comment: this is the problem it is not allowed to paste in here in my company but i can paste a piece of it: